# What does GMail app on iOS use for HTML email editing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

From what I've read UIWebView doesn't support editing, yet the GMail app on iPhone does allow you to reply to an HTML email and you can edit the HTML while doing so, not just like they put a text field above it.

**Has anyone figured out how GMail is doing this?**  Or even better, anyone that worked on the project able to give me some hints without getting in trouble?

Even with something like WebKit to render the HTML, still seems like you would have a ton of work to do to memic a lot of behaviors of a normal text field (UITextView or UITextField).

Edit: Wanted to make sure it was clear I'm talking about the actual GMail app, the one you can install from the App Store.  Not GMail POP3/IMAP via the built-in Mail app.  Obviously the built-in Mail app has access to a lot more than a 3rd party app like mine or GMail does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWebView` does support editing, as of iOS 5, by setting `contentEditable` to `true`. See [Rich Text Editing: A Simple Start](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/) for an example of a rich text editor implementation.

There's also the [DTRichTextEditor library](http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtrichtexteditor/) which I can recommend after having used it in a recent project. It supports in-line image support, video and links amongst other things.

Comment: Wow nice, I completely missed that!  My app only needs to work on iOS 5.0 and above -- perfect.